# Why my does stored procedure add columns wrong sometimes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I wrote this query to columns i.e. running records i.e. Ledger.

For example:

```
Amount  --  RunningAmount
-------------------------
200     --  500
200     --  700
500     --  1200
120     --  1320
```

As you can see that running amount is the result of addition between running amount and amount per row.

I wrote this query and it was working well.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rpt_Ledger]
    @FromDate datetime='1/26/2015',
    @ToDate datetime='1/26/2015',
    @AccountID int=17
AS
BEGIN
    Begin Try
         SELECT 
             A.AccountID, AccountTitle, Null AS TranasactionDateTime, 
             0 AS Amount,'Opening Balance' as [Description],
             SUM(T.Amount) AS RunningAmount
         FROM 
             Payments.Accounts A 
         INNER JOIN 
             Payments.Transactions T ON A.AccountID = T.Account_ID
         WHERE 
             T.Account_ID = @AccountID 
             AND T.DateTime < CONVERT(smalldatetime, @fromDate)
         GROUP BY 
             A.AccountID, A.AccountTitle 

         UNION 

         SELECT 
             A.AccountID, A.AccountTitle, A.TranasactionDateTime, 
             A.Amount, A.[Description], A.RunningAmount 
         FROM 
             (SELECT 
                  A.AccountID, A.AccountTitle, 
                  T.DateTime AS TranasactionDateTime, T.Amount, T.[Description],
                     SUM(T.Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Account_Id ORDER BY T.DateTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
                     AS RunningAmount     
              FROM Payments.Accounts A 
              INNER JOIN Payments.Transactions T ON A.AccountID = T.Account_ID
              WHERE T.Account_ID = @AccountID
             ) AS A 
        WHERE A.TranasactionDateTime >= CONVERT(smalldatetime, @fromDate) AND A.TranasactionDateTime< CONVERT(smalldatetime,DATEADD(day,1, @toDate))

    End Try
    Begin Catch
            Select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrMsg
    End Catch

END
```

But i noticed a problem, it has produced hundreds of records but i figured some values wrong

```
AMOUNT      RUNNINGAMOUNT

200.00      57300.00
200.00      57500.00
500.00      54800.00
500.00      56100.00
200.00      57700.00
200.00      58100.00
200.00      57900.00
200.00      58300.00
```

You can see that it has started adding wrongly at some points and after this it has added well again, why ? why it works good upto some level and then wrong and again right ?

Help

Comment: Firstly It was never running ok ,because it was never tested properly.You can debug by commenting out each select and see which part is giving incorrect result .Because your query appear ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple records for single Payments.Accounts.DateTime. Not sure if Payments.Transactions has a TransactionId column. If it does, You can write

```
SUM(T.Amount) OVER (
    PARTITION BY T.Account_Id 
    ORDER BY T.DateTime, T.TransactionId
)
```

Comment: Not sure if Payments.Transactions has a TransactionId column. If it has, use it.

Comment: What he's saying is that `T.DateTime` mustn't be unique. Your sample dataset did not include the `T.DateTime` column if you included it (and ordered by it) you should find that it adds up correctly over it, but there might be duplicates where it arbitrarily adds.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is lacking an ORDER BY clause, so the results may happen to be in order (as some ordering must be done anyhow to get the running total), but this is in no way guaranteed.

So you must add an ORDER BY clause and everything should be fine.

```
SELECT 
  ...
ORDER BY 
  AccountID, 
  CASE WHEN TranasactionDateTime IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, -- NULLs first
  TranasactionDateTime;
```

Why is this UNION by the way? Shouldn't this be UNION ALL? Can there be any duplicate rows you want to remove?